# Neo4j direct MATCH vs CALL apoc.cypher.mapParallel2

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I'm trying to understand what is the most proper and scalable way to write Cypher queries.

Right now I have two approaches

****#1** with pure direct MATCH:**

```
MATCH  ( childD:Vacancy )  
WHERE  exists { MATCH (childD)-[:EMPLOYMENT_AS]-(req0:Requirable) WHERE req0.id IN [21, 22, 23, 24]}  
AND  exists { MATCH (childD)-[:WORK_TIME_ZONE]-(req1:Requirable) WHERE req1.id IN [11, 12, 13, 14]}  
AND  exists { MATCH (childD)-[:COMPANY_TYPE_OF]-(req2:Requirable) WHERE req2.id IN [1, 2]}  
AND  exists { MATCH (childD)-[:EMPLOYMENT_TYPE_AS]-(req3:Requirable) WHERE req3.id IN [26, 27]}  
AND  exists { MATCH (childD)-[:LOCATED_IN]-(req4:Requirable) WHERE req4.id IN [6, 7]}  
AND  (childD.`active` = true)  AND ( (childD.`salaryUsd` >= 15330)  OR  (childD.`hourlyRateUsd` >= 81) ) 
WITH childD 
RETURN count(childD)
```

**Cypher version: CYPHER 4.4, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 231995 total db hits in 205 ms.**

[image]

**#2 the same query wrapped with apoc.cypher.mapParallel2**

```
MATCH  ( childD:Vacancy )  
WITH collect({`childD`: childD}) as childDDgRdgd  
CALL apoc.cypher.mapParallel2(" 
WITH _.childD as childD 
WHERE  exists { MATCH (childD)-[:EMPLOYMENT_AS]-(req0:Requirable) WHERE req0.id IN $reqParam0}  
AND  exists { MATCH (childD)-[:WORK_TIME_ZONE]-(req1:Requirable) WHERE req1.id IN $reqParam1}  
AND  exists { MATCH (childD)-[:COMPANY_TYPE_OF]-(req2:Requirable) WHERE req2.id IN $reqParam2}  
AND  exists { MATCH (childD)-[:EMPLOYMENT_TYPE_AS]-(req3:Requirable) WHERE req3.id IN $reqParam3}  
AND  exists { MATCH (childD)-[:LOCATED_IN]-(req4:Requirable) WHERE req4.id IN $reqParam4}  AND  (childD.`active` = $active7)  
AND ( (childD.`salaryUsd` >= $salaryUsd5)  OR  (childD.`hourlyRateUsd` >= $hourlyRateUsd6) ) 
WITH childD 
RETURN childD  
", {`hourlyRateUsd6`:81, `reqParam4`:[6, 7], `reqParam3`:[26, 27], `salaryUsd5`:15330, `reqParam2`:[1, 2], `reqParam1`:[11, 12, 13, 14], `reqParam0`:[21, 22, 23, 24], `active7`:true}, childDDgRdgd, 6, 10) 
YIELD value as value   
WITH value.childD as childD  
RETURN count(childD)
```

**Cypher version: CYPHER 4.4, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 10001 total db hits in 114 ms**

[image]

As you may see, the approach with `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2` works ~2 times faster, but I'm not sure if this is a right and scalable way. Please advise - am I doing right when wrap the query with `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2` ? What is the correct and scalable way of executing such query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when it comes to scaling queries, data-remodeling is first suggested in place of parallelization. But if the model is as best as it can be, then parallelization is the way to go. Also, `apoc.map.parallel2` is expected to give performance benefits, as it aims to utilize all the CPU cores, and combines outputs from multiple threads, likewise, as you have seen.

So, yes I think it's a good way of executing the query. However, it's also non-performant in some cases, as discussed in this [Neo4j Community Discussion](https://community.neo4j.com/t5/neo4j-graph-platform/how-best-to-do-parallel-processing/td-p/23094).
This is an old article, but it will be worth completely trying out all the scenarios, before relying on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My biggest worry is about `MATCH  ( childD:Vacancy )  
WITH collect({`childD`: childD}) as childDDgRdgd  
CALL apoc.cypher.mapParallel2(" ` Let's say I have 1 million nodes. Will this approach iterate through 1 million nodes in order to find the right match ? Instead of only matching the interconnected nodes?

Comment: Both approaches will do that. For every `childD` node the checks in the `where` clause will be applied, whether you use `apoc.map.parallel2` or not. The only difference is, non-apoc version, will do it serially on a single thread, apoc version will distribute it among the thread.